# Configure a transparent Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-elb

I want to create an Elastic Load Balancer in front of my SSL site which simply passes through ports 80 and 443. I do not want my Elastic Load Balancer to have an SSL certificate of its own, I just want it to pass traffic forward to my single server.

Is there a way to do this transparently? It's now asking me to import a certificate as I'm creating the Elastic Load Balancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to configure an ELB that balances TCP, not HTTPS. If you do this, it will not ask you for a certificate.